# "in" property in Extbase for querying multi-values in TYPO3

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

The "in" property used in Extbase does not seem to be working for me.

`$actor` contains an array of `Actor model objects`.  My `Movie model` and `Actor` are in m:n relation.

I tried something like this in my `Movie Repository`:

```
$query=$this->createQuery();
$query->matching($query->in('actors',$actors));
$result = $query->execute()->toArray();
```

`$result` is showing `NULL`

I tried passing array of `actor uids` too but that wont work as well:

```
$query->matching($query->in('actors',[$actor_1_uid,$actor_2_uid]));
```

There is of course `contains` but using `in` should be more convenient.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any problem in your statement. Just to be clear, a "in" statement must be placed somewhere inside a matching statement, which is correct in your case.

However, you should change your create query for

```
$query = $this->createQuery();
```

instead of

```
$query=$this->create->query();
```

If you have still no result, I suggest you check the exact the SQL statement executed by extbase, there's a tricky way to do it in TYPO3.

You have to locate the following file in the core:/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Generic/Storage/Typo3DbBackend.php

locate the replacePlaceHolders function and add the following codes at the end of the function:

```
if (strpos( $sqlString, "my_table_name" ) !== false) {
echo $sqlString;
}
```

I will echo every statement that is being made for the following "my_table_name" table. Of course, never do that in your production server.

I hope it will help!
Cheers,
Olivier

Comment: That's really handy. Thank You :)

Comment: I have written the echo statement. My extension is a backend module. But it is not giving any output. Why it is so?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but `$query->in` is the wrong approach. AFAIK it will not work for m:n reations, only for 1:n.

Try something like this, *$actors* being a query result from the model or the actors repository:

```
$constraints = array();
foreach ($actors as $actor) {
  $constraints[] = $query->contains('actors', $actor->getUid());
}

if (!empty($constraints)) {
  $result = $query->matching($query->logicalOr($constraints))->execute();
}
```

Of course you can use your own array of uids for the loop, then just drop the `getUid()` method

Comment: Shouldn't logicalOr have two arguments?

Comment: `logicalOr` takes multiple constraints OR an array ... see http://goo.gl/GWojt0 (and http://api.typo3.org/extbase/)